# finding a string in a string if it is at the beginning of a word

Tags: php

I want to search if a word/phrase is there within a string (~max 300 char) and I am using:

```
if (strpos($currentString,$searchWord) !== false) {
  .....
}
```

The code works fine for exact matches and also for partial matches such as: search word bayes in bayesian, which is fine. But problem is that it also finds search word in fusion in diffusion. I would like to find if the search word is an entire word or at the beginning of a word within the string. And I would like to avoid when the search word is at the end/ middle of a word within the string.

Any suggestion would be of great help.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Regex.

```
if( preg_match('(\b'.preg_quote($searchWord).'\w*)i',$currentString,$match)) {
    echo $searchWord . " matched the word ".$match[0]."!";
}
```

Notice how you can use it to get the whole word that was found as well? :)

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Sure, but the entire matched word could be of interest - otherwise I wouldn't even bother with the `$match` capture variable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I misread the question. Btw, I think you're missing delimiters.

Comment: @nhbjgfcxhgchg actually parenthesis are valid delimeters.

Comment: Well, I'll be damned... :)

Comment: @rjdown then how would you find if the match was the start of a word?

Comment: @rjdown OP is looking for the start of a word, not just string.

Comment: @rjdown And YOU had better read the QUESTION. Start of a WORD, not start of the STRING.

Comment: @FreeBenzine Regardless of all the chatter, this is the correct answer to do what you are describing. It will find a needle (small string) in hackstack (larger string) where the needle is at the start of a word or the whole word itself. It works by using the boundary `\b` match in a regular expression which will match the edge of a word such as beginning or end. The only place this might be an issue is with hyphenated words like `sub-string`. This will match `str` as the start of `string`. Same issue for contraction words where some chars are replaced with `'`. Up to you if that is an issue.

Answer (score -3):

```
if(substr($currentString,0,300) == $searchWord){

}
```

Comment: oops, missed the partial match :S